# How can I change global variable when it's showed in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript

The global variable called "GV" own its original value. And when I call certain function by clicking some buttons in HTML page, GV would be changed. Then, I want to show GV in my HTML page by calling alert() or anything else. But GV has no change. How can I do this?

Comment: Please take a look on the [assign(=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) operator to change variable values and on the [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) function to display alerts. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 ways to specify a value as a global one:

1. On the top scope. `var someGlobal = "some value";`
2. Without using var at all `someGlobal = "some value";`
3. Explicitely using the window object. `window.GV = "some value";`

So in your case, this will normally work wherever you are in the code:

`window.GV = "some value";
alert(window.GV);`

Note: 1. is risky because if you change the scope or if your script gets encapsulated you loose the global variable. 2. Same problem while using preprocessors where your code will also be compiled within a module before being executed. 3. normally the most reliable way to assign a global variable.

Comment: Add a leading line and also explain why this answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to create a global is to add "window." in front of your variable.

```
window.GV = 0;

function testOne() {
    window.GV = 'Hi !';
}

testOne();

setTimeout(function () {
    alert(window.GV);
}, 500);
```

Comment: In my instance, the function testOne() shouldn't be called here, but called in one click on a button in HTML. like this:
`<html><body>
      <button onClick="testOne()"/>
</body></html>` 
then GV will be showed by another click, not preriodically.

Comment: It's just an example, remove testOne(); and try to click on the button with your event onClick="testOne()"